# How to solve system of differential equations containing heaviside function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have this sets of equations
\begin{align}
x_1'[t] &= x_2[t]
\\
x_2'[t] &= -p_2[t]
\\
p_1'[t]&=-x_1[t]
\\
p_2'[t]&=-p_1[t] - p_3 (-2 H_2 (3 - x_2[t]) + 2 H_1 (3 + x_2[t]))
\\
p_3'[t]&=0
\end{align}
where $H_i$ are Heaviside functions defined as

$
H_1= \begin{cases}
0,&for \qquad-(3 + x_2[t])\geq 0\\
1,&for \qquad-(3 + x_2[t])<0
\end{cases}
$

$
H_2= \begin{cases}
0,&for \qquad-(3 - x_2[t])\geq 0\\
1,&for \qquad-(3 - x_2[t])<0
\end{cases}
$

I know Mathematica can solve systems of equations, but I don't know how to integrate a Heaviside function.

How can I solve this system of equations. Actually I know initial values of $x_i$ but don't know $p_i$ since they are Lagrange multipliers of the Hamiltonian equation.

I know that;

$p_1[t_f]=p_2[t_f]=0$ where $t_f$ is not defined it is free.

Comment: Not actually. I don't know that much for Laplace transform for this type of equations. Btw, what is the transform of heaviside?

Comment: @Moo actually I have missed to replace u[t] it is equal to -p2[t] a am going to edit it. I need to find Laplace transofrm of all the 5 equations and than do the substitution to find them lastly I need to take inverse transform. Right?

Comment: I still coudn't compute the Laplace transform of Heaviside function. It does not depend explicitly to variable t and the function multiplied by.

Comment: I have already seen that page, but still couldn't make it similar to that in the forum. I have heavyside function like this $x_2 [t]-3$ which is a function of t or one of which $x_2$has negative sign.

Comment: You can see that $x_2 '[t]$ has terms like $H_1*(3-x_2[t])$ where $H_1$ is Heaviside defined as in the question.

Comment: I just imlimented that subscript so that I can indicate that those are two different Heavisides. Not for the shifting term.

Comment: One of my lecturer has asked as a homework question which is an example question from the book with a little change. And I red the section and the derivation of equations which defines those Heavisides but no solution of integration.